# Dynamic API CALL/ Retrieving specific Attributes

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am doing an API call and data fetching with Fetch function on a platform listing different products with their data identified by attributes, here I am trying to fetch multiple attributes of a specific category of product, each product is identified by a unique serial number, which serves as my entry key to retrieve product data.
Or the attributes that I retrieve do not exist for certain products, either the field exists but the data is null, or the field is not filled in on the platform for this product.
I neutralize nulls with the formula you can see on my script but it doesn't always work, I would like to know if I can make my API even more dynamic, i.e. retrieve attributes only when they exist and when the presence of a null does not block the API call.

```
 function GetAllProduct() {

var token=ConnectAlkemics();

//Logger.log(token);
var headers ={
  "accept": "*/*",
  "accept-language": "fr",
  'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token,
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  'expires': '-1',
  'pragma': 'no-cache',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'x-alk-priority': '9'
  };

 var options ={
  'method' : "GET",
  "headers" : headers
 };

 var source =SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("GTIN");
 var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("RESULTATS");

 ss.clear();
 //  var dico=CreerDicoHeader();

//retrieving list of attribute
 var lastRow = source.getLastRow();

 var listeAttribut = "";
 var listeChamp = "";
 var tabChamp = [];
 var index = 0;
for(var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++ ){
//Logger.log(i);
  if(source.getRange(i, 3).getValue() != ""){
   tabChamp[index] = source.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
   index +=1;
   if(listeAttribut == ""){
     listeAttribut = source.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
     listeChamp = source.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    }
    else{
     listeAttribut = listeAttribut + "," + source.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
     listeChamp = listeChamp + "," + source.getRange(i, 2).getValue();}
   }
 }



   var total=0;
   var debut=2;
   var moregtin=true
   var lignegtin=1;


  var colonnes=[
        "GTIN",
        "Libelle long",
        "Fournisseur",
        "Catégorie du produit",
        "Code Tiers",
        "Cycle de vie",
        "Maturité commande Galec",
        "Maturité direct magasin" ,
        "Maturité Commande SCABEL",
        "Maturité complémentaire Galec",
        "Maturité complémentaire Direct Magasin",
        "Maturité complémentaire Scabel",
        "Maturité Animation Digitale",
        "Maturité Digitale",
        "Maturité Entité Leclerc",
        "Type d'unité",
        "Marque Commerciale",
        "Appellation viticole ou région d'origine",
        "Complément d'appellation(N)",
        "Packaging vin",
        "Contenu net",
        "Description des saveurs du vin",
        "Type de champagne(N)",
        "Viticulture(N)",
        "Couleur du Vin",
        "Millésime",
        "Terroirs et sol(N)",
        "Région Viticole",
        "Durée du potentiel de maturation",
        "Echelle de fruit",
        "Echelle de personnalité",
        "Dégustation robe",
        "Dégustation nez",
         "Type de vendange(N)",
         "Dégustation bouche",
         "Type d'appellation du vin",
         "Allergènes avérés",
         "Type d'allergène",
         "Degré d'alcool",
         "Teneur en sucre",
         "Description du cépage",
         "Accords mets et vins",
         "Occasions particulières",
         "Températures de dégustation (en °c)",
         "Potentiel de garde",
         "Code de nomenclature douanière",
         "Code produit accise france",
         "Libellé fiscal",
         "Pays d'origine",
         "Type de paiement des droits d'alcools",
         "Image Face du produit",
         "Image Arrière du produit",
          ];


      var colonnematurite=6; //Colonnes 

for(i=0;i<colonnes.length;i++) {
  ss.getRange(1,i+1).setValue(colonnes[i]);
}

//for(i=0; i<tabChamp.length; i++){
//  ss.getRange(1,i+1).setValue(tabChamp[i]);
  //Logger.log(tabChamp[i]);
//}


  while (moregtin==true)
 {
  var fini=false;
  var nbgtin=0;
  var lesgtin="";
  var produits =[];


while ((source.getRange(lignegtin,1).getValue()!="") && (nbgtin<50)) //paquets de 50 GTINs
{
  if (lesgtin!="") 
    lesgtin=lesgtin+",";
  lesgtin=lesgtin+source.getRange(lignegtin,1).getValue().toString().replace(/\s+/g," ").trim();
  lignegtin=lignegtin+1;
  nbgtin=nbgtin+1;
}

if (lesgtin=="")
{
  moregtin=false;
  fini=true;
}
else
{
  var limit=200;
  var next_page='';  
  var lastparam='';
  
  var params =lastparam + 'status_shared_from=4' + lesgtin + '&filter_source_include=uuid,gtin,namePublicLong,namePublicShort,isSharedFrom.sourceOrganization.nameLegal,endAvailabilityDateTime,supplierId,business_processes,brand.description,lastOrderDateTime,isUserLabeledByName,lifeCycle,typePackaging,isConsumerUnit,isBaseUnit,isDisplayUnit,assets,pictures,exportables'

  var params =lastparam + '&filter_product_languages=fr&filter_gtins_in=' + lesgtin + '&filter_source_include=' + listeAttribut

  var lesparams =params + '&limit=' + limit + '&next_page=' + next_page + '&ts=' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 1);
}

while (fini==false) {
  var lesparams =params + '&limit=' + limit + '&next_page=' + next_page + '&ts=' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 1);
  var url='https://apis.alkemics.com/public/v1/products?'+lesparams;
  //Logger.log(url);  
  var content =UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  //Logger.log(content);
  //Logger.log(content.getResponseCode())
  if (content.getResponseCode() ==200) {   
    var retour =JSON.parse(content.getContentText());
    next_page=retour.next_page;
    var data=retour.data;
    for(i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
      var produit=data[i]; // Un produit au format JSON
      var libellelong="";
      try
      {
        libellelong=produit.namePublicLong[0].data;
      }
      catch(e) {
        libellelong="";
        //libelle="NA"
      }
      
      var libellecourt="";
      try
      {
        libellecourt=produit.namePublicShort[0].data;
      }
      catch(e) {
        libellecourt="";
        //libelle="NA"
      }
      
      var maturite={}
      for(k=0;k<produit.business_processes.length;k++)
      {
        maturite[produit.business_processes[k].label]=(produit.business_processes[k].requested==false?"":(produit.business_processes[k].status==true?"OK":"KO"));
      }
      var listematurite={}
      for(k=0;k<produit.business_processes.length;k++)
      {
        listematurite[k]=produit.business_processes[k].label;
      }
  
      var marque=""
      if ("brand" in produit) {
        if ("description" in produit.brand)
         marque=produit.brand.description;
      }
      var occasionwhine="" 
      if (" occasions" in produit) {
        if("occasion" in produit.occasions[0])
         occasionwhine = produit.occasions[0].occasion.label
      }
      
      var pairing=""
      if (" pairingsTypes" in produit) {
        if("pairingsType" in produit.pairingsTypes[0])
         pairing = produit.pairingsTypes[0].pairingsType.label
      }

      var mediaface= ""
      if (" assets" in produit) {
        if("pictures" in produit.assets)
         if("exportables" in produit.assets.pictures[0])
          mediaface= produit.assets.pictures[0].exportables[0].uniformResourceIdentifier
      }
      var mediaback
      if (" assets" in produit) {
        if("pictures" in produit.assets)
         if("exportables" in produit.assets.pictures[2])
          mediaback= produit.assets.pictures[2].exportables[0].uniformResourceIdentifier
      }
      //var ConsumerUnit = (produit.isConsumerUnit == false ?"":(produit.isBaseUnit==true?"UC":"LOT"))
      //var Presentoir    = (produit.isDisplayUnit  == true ? produit.typePackaging.label : "")
     
      var ligne=[
        produit.gtin, 
        libellelong,
        produit.isSharedFrom[0].sourceOrganization.nameLegal,
        produit.kind != null? produit.kind.label: ' ',
        produit.supplierId,
        produit.lifeCycle,
       //(produit.endAvailabilityDateTime==null?"":TIMESTAMP_TO_DATE(produit.endAvailabilityDateTime)),
       //produit.isUserLabeledByName,
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite]],
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite+1]],
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite+2]],
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite+3]],
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite+4]],
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite+5]],
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite+6]],
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite+7]],
        maturite[tabChamp[colonnematurite+8]],
        produit.typePackaging.label,
        marque, 
        produit['alcoholicBeverageSubregionText'],  
        produit['alcoholicBeverageAdditionalAppellationDetailsText'],   
        produit.leclercWinePackagingTypeCode != null?  produit.leclercWinePackagingTypeCode.label : ' ',  
        produit.netWeight[0] != null?  produit.netWeight[0].data: ' ',  

produit.wineTastingDescriptionList[0] != null?  
        produit.wineTastingDescriptionList[0].wineTastingCode.label : ' ', 
        produit.wineCategoryCode != null? produit.wineCategoryCode.label: ' ', 
        produit.vintnerTextList,  

        produit.colorGroup != null?  produit.colorGroup.label: ' ', 
        produit.vintage, 
        produit.vineyardRegion != null? produit.vineyardRegion.label: ' ', 
        produit.leclercFrenchVineyardRegionCode != null? produit.leclercFrenchVineyardRegionCode.label: ' ',   
        produit.wineAgeingPotentialDurationCode != null? produit.wineAgeingPotentialDurationCode.label: ' ',  
        produit.wineFruitExpressionNoteNumber, 
        produit.wineAromasExpressionNoteNumber, 
        produit.wineTastingRobeDescriptionText[0] != null?  produit.wineTastingRobeDescriptionText[0].data: ' ', 
        produit.wineTastingNoseDescriptionText[0] != null? produit.wineTastingNoseDescriptionText[0].data: ' ', 
        produit['grapeHarvestingDescriptionText'].data,  
        produit.wineTastingMouthDescriptionText[0] != null? produit.wineTastingMouthDescriptionText[0].data:' ',  
        produit.wineCategoryCode != null? produit.wineCategoryCode.label: ' ', 
        produit.allergens[0] != null? produit.allergens[0].data : ' ',  
        produit.allergenTypeList,  
        produit.ratioAlcohol, 
        produit.sugarContent != null? produit.sugarContent.label: ' ',  
        produit.varietalDesignationDescriptionText[0] != null? produit.varietalDesignationDescriptionText[0].data:' ', 
        pairing,
        
        //produit.pairingsTypes[0] != null? produit.pairingsTypes[0].pairingsType.label: ' ',
        occasionwhine,
        //produit.occasions[0].occasion != null? produit.occasions[0].occasion.label: ' ' , //+ "," + produit.occasions[1],
        produit.tempConsumption[0] != null? produit.tempConsumption[0].data: ' ', 
        produit.wineAgeingPotentialDurationCode != null?  produit.wineAgeingPotentialDurationCode.label : ' ', 
        produit.importEuropeanClassification,  
        produit.cpaFranceCode.label, 
        produit.taxLabelList[0] != null? produit.taxLabelList[0].taxLabelCode.label: ' ', 
        produit.countryOfOriginList[0] != null? produit.countryOfOriginList[0].countryOfOriginCode.label: ' ',  
        produit.alcoholicBeveragePaymentTypeCode != null? produit.alcoholicBeveragePaymentTypeCode.label: ' ',
        mediaface,
        mediaback,
        //produit.assets.pictures[0].exportables[0] != null? produit.assets.pictures[0].exportables[0].uniformResourceIdentifier: ' ',
       // produit.assets.pictures[2].exportables[0] != null? produit.assets.pictures[2].exportables[0].uniformResourceIdentifier: ' ',
        
        
        //ConsumerUnit,
        //Presentoir
      ];


     
         
      produits.push(ligne);
      total=total+1;
    }
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('Error in GET /contents/{contentid}')
  }
```

Comment: That's a  fairly large example.  Do you have a specific area where you having a particular problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i've tried to give more details and explanations about my problem in the comment below.